# C++ struct declaration in class

Tags: c++, struct

I want to have a struct in one class,
like this:

```
namespace C {
    class H
    {
        struct A
        {
            .....
        };
        //other members
    };

    class R {
      //R's members
    };
}
```

and in another header file just using a `name d.h`, I need to declare these classes, for example:

```
namespace C
{
   class H;
   class R;
}
```

Now my problem is, how to declare `struct A` in `d.h` file?

can I use

```
namespace C
{
   class H {struct A;}
   class R;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to. `A` is `C::H::A`. Folk who only know a forward definition of `H` probably shouldn't know about `H::A`. If they need to know, why put it in `R`? `R::A` will not be the same type as `H::A`.